# Tool to check site in IE 11

Tags: html, css

I am using windows-xp which doesn't support IE 11.My site shows some design problem in IE 11.So I need a tool to check site.Is there any tool which help me?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft ofers virtual machines for testing, look hier: [VMs of IE for OSX, Linux or Windows](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools)

Further more I know only [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) but these emulators will not show you everthing right

Comment: I would go with the virtual machines since; it allows you to use the dev tools to see what if anything is causing issues.

They are a little more complicated to set up (not by much though) and you will gain a hell of a lot more debugging than the other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can also try aaplet ietest or put a virtual machine with windows 7/8

Answer (score 0):

Try this - [netrender](http://netrenderer.com/)

> IE NetRenderer allows you to check how a website is rendered by Internet Explorer 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6 or 5.5, as seen from a high speed datacenter located in Germany. Just type in a URL in the field above and try it out - it's free! Unlike other screenshot services, we are able to process a large number of capturing jobs in parallel and in realtime, making it the fastest service that we know of.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is a very useful link for checking other browsers.

http://browserhots.org/